# how to add a button in custom openerp module

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I am having an error while adding a button of type action .I cannot view my button . 
Following is my `vetclinic_view.xml`

```
<record id="vetclinic_breed_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
         <field name="name">Breed</field>
         <field name="res_model">vetclinic.breed</field>
         <button name="add_field" string="Add Field" type="object"  class="oe_highlight" />
         <field name="view_type">form</field>
         <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
         <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click create record.</p>
         </field>
```

Here is my `vetclinic.py`

```
class vetclinic_breed(osv.Model):
_name="vetclinic.breed"
_columns={
     'name':fields.char('Name',size=32),    
          }
def add_field(cr,self,uid,id):
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be in your vetclinic_view.xml file but it is a window action, not a view. Note the model attribute of the record element.

You need to add the button to the view, not the action. The window action is responsible for triggering the view display but it isn't the view.

Comment: How to do this, because I will also want to add action to my button

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a form and tree view for this model. Add the button in there. If you want to execute some code, make the button name the name of your subroutine and give it a type of object, then in your model have that method.

Your button will look like this:

```
<button name="button_add_field" string="Add Field" type="object"/>
```

And your method will look like this:

```
   def button_add_fieldself, cr, uid, ids, context = None):
        do stuff
        return True
```

Update: Have a look at the invoice_form in the account module account_invoice_view.xml for an example.

Comment: look I have to add the button definition xml in view ?

Answer (score 0):

insert button like this in form view.

class.py file

def name_of_method():

blaw blaw blaw

button will work fine and remember one more thing , button can't be used in tree view